# How tot use an Enum member as index for a Record<S,O> type?

Tags: typescript, enums

For a library I want to allow the user to modify it's config by means of some presets. My idea is to provide an Enum with all possible presets exported with the select function.

Unfortunately, I could not get it completely as I had in mind, due to some weird behavior of the type checker.

The code below does provide the presets and the select method, but it requires an "illegal" preset. When I remove it (a.1), the type checker complains that my Presets does not have an index property. Alternatively, one can keep that illegal preset in the enum, but that requires also that the Presets const has a property added with the enum value as key.

Another issue is that I cannot use the enum to create the Presets const itself. When I uncomment (b.2) all remains valid and function, but when I then comment (b.1) the type checker compains that the type of the literal is not compatible (b.3)

What do I do wrong?

```js
export enum Preset
{
    EASY = 'one',
    DEFAULT = 'two',
    HARD = 'three',
    IMPOSSIBLE = 'do_not_use' // (a.1)
}

type Config = Record<'a' | 'b', number>
type PresetNames = Preset.DEFAULT | Preset.EASY | Preset.HARD
type ConfigByPreset = Record<PresetNames, Config>

/* (b.3)
 * [ts] Type '{ [x: string]: { a: number; b: number; }; one: { a: number; b: number; }; two: { a: number; b: nu...' 
 * is not assignable to type 'Record<PresetNames, Record<"a" | "b", number>>'.
 * Property 'three' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: { a: number; b: number; }; one: { a: number; b: number; }; 
 * two: { a: number; b: nu...'.
 */
const Presets: ConfigByPreset = {
    one: { a: 1, b: 101 },
    two: { a: 2, b: 201 },
    ['three']: { a: 3, b: 301 },        // (b.1)
    // [Preset.HARD]: { a: 4, b: 301 }, // (b.2)
}

const defaultConfig = Presets[Preset.DEFAULT]

export function selectPreset( preset: PresetNames ) 
{
    // (a.2) [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Record<Preset, Record<"a" | "b", number>>' has no index signature.
    const selectedConfig = Presets[preset]
    const otherConfig = Presets['three']

    console.log( 'config = ', selectedConfig, otherConfig, defaultConfig )
}

selectPreset( Preset.EASY )
```

Comment: What version of typescript are you using... I'm not really seeing the errors in the playground ..

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it was 3.2, but my Eclipse was set to use it's internal compiler, which is 2.x

Answer (score 0):

As Titian Cernicova pointed out, I was just using an older Typescript compiler. Eclipse allows you to use a project-specific compiler, but I neglected to adjust the project configuration.